# Sent text (SMS) messages sometimes show up under wrong contact's conversation

Tags: contacts, sms, handcent-sms

I'm on a Nexus One with Android 2.3.7 (CyanogenMod-7.2.0-passion), and recently I've noticed some sent messages go into the wrong contact's conversation: I send a message to person ABC, the person does receive it correctly, but when I check later the app shows it as sent to a different person XYZ. This really messes up the conversation and gets confusing quickly.

This has happened thrice so far, and there doesn't seem to be any pattern to it except both the contacts involved were people I had been messaging recently at those times. Note that the correct contact does receive the message, it's only on the display of the Sent message that this bug happens.

I'm using Handcent app, but the same display issue occurs in the default Messaging app. In both cases, the message details that comes up after a long press on the message shows the correct number. But somehow, it is still shown under the wrong contact. I've also tried restarting the phone, doesn't help.

Edit: I checked them all, and there does seem to be a pattern here - in each case, if a message ("msg1") sent to A is wrongly displayed under B, it turns out that B was the person I sent the next SMS after "msg1". That is, I send "msg1" to A, then after some time (varies from a few hours to a few days) I send a different message ("msg2") to B, "msg1" and "msg2" both end up under contact B one after the other

Comment: Do the phone numbers of the two contacts show some similarities, e.g. ending with the same X digits (in an extreme case: identical numbers with just different country prefixes)? Or are the "wrongly listed" places only depending on "recently messaged contacts", and it might be a different "place" each time it happens?

Comment: I checked the numbers, there isn't any visible consistent similarities among them: one pair has the 4th and 5th digits as the same, another has 4th and 6th digits, another has only the 8th digit the same between them. Looks like only random, chance correlation. 

I don't understand your second question though, could you explain what you mean?

Comment: The first part was referring to "number matching": some algorithms only check the last N digits whether they're matching, so 0123-4567890 and 0321-4567890 would be counted similar on N=7. That's obviously not the case here. Second part was a raw guess: You message A, then B, and the last msg gets applied to A (while sent correctly to B). Now you message C, then A, and A gets the last msg, but it's stored to C? That would make a pattern ("stored to previous"), though it makes no sense. Enough time between the two messages, and they get stored correctly?

Comment: Yes, there does seem to be a pattern of that kind here! I checked them all, and in each case, if a message ("msg1") sent to A is wrongly displayed under B, it turns out that B was the person I sent the next SMS after "msg1". That is, I send "msg1" to A, then after some time (varies from a few hours to a few days) I send a different message ("msg2") to B, "msg1" and "msg2" both end up under contact B one after the other.

Comment: That's very strange! Though I know of no solution to this: would you please [edit] your question and include this discovery, so it's easier to find? That way it might attract some attention from others having experienced the same, and improves chances for possible answers. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds related to that old [SMS bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9392) from 2010, where messages were being sent to the wrong person.